# list-style não volta ao padrão

Tags: html, css

Bom, estou desenvolvendo um site, e me surgiu o seguinte problema:

Dei um reset em todos os elementos do site;

```
*{
    color:inherit;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    font-weight:inherit;
    background-color:inherit;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    list-style:none;
}
```

Porém, agora preciso usar uma lista com as bolinhas da lista, então usei o css abaixo:

```
.video-description ul,.video-description ol{
    list-style:initial;
    list-style-type:disc;
    list-style-position:outside;
    list-style-image:initial;
    padding:0 0 0 24px;
    margin:12px 0 24px;
}
```

Porém, as bolinhas não voltam a aparecer, como posso corrigir o problema ? (testei com uma ul normal)

Comment: Tenta dar um !important

Comment: não rodou man :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O estilo `list-style` é aplicado ao elemento `li`. Como a sua redefinição para disco está apenas no `ul`, no caso a definição em `*` é aplicada.

Para corrigir, defina a regra para os elementos `li`:

```css
* {
  color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

.video-description ul,
.video-description ol {
  list-style-type: disc;
  list-style-position: outside;
  list-style-image: initial;
  padding: 0 0 0 24px;
  margin: 12px 0 24px;
}
.video-description ul li,
.video-description ol li {
  list-style: initial;
}
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Lista fora dos divs
</h1>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr />
<h1>
Lista ul
</h1>
<div class="video-description">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: perfeito, rodou

Comment: `+1` - junta um exemplo para ficar mais completa a resposta (https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/vsxpoan3/)

Comment: obrigado pela sugestão Sergio, exemplo adicionado